# Alexa AudioPlayer Requests (IE PlaybackStarted) Not Being Sent?

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit

I've been using this template: https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-python-audio-player/tree/master/MultiStream

As well as: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html#playlist-progression

To try and get a list of mp3's to play. However, even though I'm able to manually say "next" to get each file to play, the Interface methods "PlaybackNearlyFinished" or "PlaybackStarted" don't seem to be sending at all (no logs or anything). I'm at a loss why this would be the case, seeing as I can manually trigger the audio to play (through an intent).

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

I do get some errors after the initially playback saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/ask_sdk_core/skill_builder.py", line 109, in wrapper
    request_envelope=request_envelope, context=context)
  File "/var/task/ask_sdk_core/skill.py", line 190, in invoke
    persistence_adapter=self.persistence_adapter)
  File "/var/task/ask_sdk_core/attributes_manager.py", line 107, in __init__
    "Cannot get SessionAttributes from out of session request!")
```

However, I've logged every place I reference the attributes (they work) and these errors are don't seem to be originating from something I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I think that was a problem in [SDK](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-python/commit/c38519d117c6884da8743ee1e2559c99dfd3602e#diff-8b2153cb9d6aeec20cac0273a74d6ea4). They have fixed in the latest release, after updating to the latest version I did not have that issue.

The problem was in the ask-SDK-core, there are more details [here](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-python/commits/master/ask-sdk-core)